# Hide graphs when knit in R

Tags: r

I am working on a .rmd file and want to knit my file into html. So far, I am able to hide code chunks, results and comments using below but my html file still shows graphs from my code.

````
```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, results = 'hide' }
count(data, col1, col2) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = col1, y = n, fill = reorder(col2, desc(n))))
```
````

Could you please advise what command I should use to hide my graph in the html output?

Comment: `fig.show = 'hide'`. To hide everything, use `include = FALSE` - this will take hide the code, results, messages, warnings, plots, etc., but still evaluate the code.

Comment: FYI, I just went to the [knitr chunk options webpage](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/), clicked on "plots", it was pretty easy to find.